# How do I make a monopoly style board game layout with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I just want to layout some squares outlining in a square shape, like the tiles of a monopoly board.
I am pretty terrible at css, just want to get the layout going then I am sure I can make it pretty with some messing around.

Comment: A table might even get you by with that. You're going to have to at least try something yourself though.

Answer (score 5):

You can either use a table or any kind of element. In my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAvjH/1/), I'm using a list in which I float the list items and make them square.

```
.field {
  width: 2.2em;
  height: 2.2em;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Nice work. Advance to Pall Mall